# Show the total reputation across sites in the Stack Exchange user profile page

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, profile-page, users

I'm talking about [this profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/bf98bcd2-c7f3-432a-a9a9-46527a8c7dff) page:

[image]

Something like this maybe:

[image]

or:

[image]

<sup>*The eagle eyed viewer might have noticed that the last one was created using free hand techniques.</sup>

I suppose other things might be added to, but this is "missing" and seems like a basic useful feature that would make sense.(?)

Comment: It does look like *something* should go in that wide white open space.  Either a reputation score, or maybe a unicorn.

Comment: I agree... it does seem like there is a bit of lack of reward for utilizing the other sites in the StackExchange network since you have to start over every time...  it would be nice to at least be acknowledged as a valuable contributor, even if it doesn't bring any extra privileges.